# Status 405 from the task queue

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, python-2.7

I want to resolve a status 405 that I get from the task queue when trying to generate a report:

```
2012-02-16 03:56:53.012 /report/ 405 3ms 0kb AppEngine-Google; (+http://code.google.com/appengine)

2012-02-16 03:56:53.007 /createreport/ 302 20ms 0kb Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:2.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/4.0
I 2012-02-16 03:56:52.990 creating report task
```

The code that creates the task is

```
class CreateReportHandler(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        logging.info('creating report task')
        taskqueue.add(url=r'/report/')
        self.redirect('/')
```

and I have it routed with webapp2:

```
Route(r'/createreport/', handler=CreateReportHandler, name='createreport'),
```

then I should be able to make it a cron job but when I test it I get a 405 from the access of this code which times out if I try to run it directly:

```
class Report(webapp2.RequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        # Create a conversion request from HTML to PDF.
        users = User.query()
        today = date.today()
        startdate = date(today.year, today.month, 1) # first day of month   
        html = None     
        for user in users: 
            if user.activity() > 0:
                logging.info('found active user %s %s' % (user.firstname, user.lastname))
                html = '<html><body><table border="1">'
                html = html + '<tr><td>ORDER</td><td colspan="2">----DISTRIBUTOR----</td><td>ORDER</td><td>Silver</td><td>%</td><td>Total</td><td>Bonus</td></tr>'
                level = user.level()
                distributor = user
                while distributor.has_downline():
                    downline = User.query(User.sponsor == distributor.key).order(User.lastname).fetch()
                    for person in downline:  # to this for whole downline
                        orders = model.Order.all().filter('distributor_id =' , person.key.id()).filter('created >' , startdate).filter('status =', 'PAID').fetch(999999)
                        silver = 0
                        name = person.firstname +' '+ person.lastname
                        for order in orders:
                            logging.info('found orders')
                            for idx,item in enumerate(order.items):
                                purchase = model.Item.get_by_id(long(item.id()))
                                amount = int(order.amounts[idx])
                                silver = silver + amount*purchase.silver/1000.000 
                            if len(name) > 13:
                                name = name[13]
                            html = html + '<tr><td>' + str(order.created.date().day)+'/'+ str(order.created.date().month )+'</td><td>' + filters.makeid(person.key.id()) +'</td><td>' + name + '</td><td>' + str(order.key().id()) + '</td><td>' + str(silver) 
                            dist_level = order.dist_level
                            bonus = 0   
                            if level == 5 and dist_level == 4:                          
                                bonus = 0.05
                            if level == 5 and dist_level == 3:
                                bonus = 0.1
                            if level == 5 and dist_level == 2:
                                bonus = 0.13
                            if level == 5 and dist_level == 1:
                                bonus = 0.35

                            if level == 4 and dist_level == 3:                          
                                bonus = 0.05
                            if level == 4 and dist_level == 2:
                                bonus = 0.08
                            if level == 4 and dist_level == 1:
                                bonus = 0.3

                            if level == 3 and dist_level == 2:                          
                                bonus = 0.03
                            if level == 3 and dist_level == 1:
                                bonus = 0.25

                            if level == 2 and dist_level == 1:                          
                                bonus = 0.2

                            html = html + '</td><td>' + str(bonus) + '</td><td>' + str(order.total)
                            bonusmoney = bonus * float(order.total)
                            html = html + '</td><td>' + str(bonusmoney) + '</td></tr>'

                        distributor = person

                html = html + '</table>'

            asset = conversion.Asset("text/html", html, "test.html")
            conversion_obj = conversion.Conversion(asset, "application/pdf")        
            rpc = conversion.create_rpc()
            conversion.make_convert_call(rpc, conversion_obj)

            result = rpc.get_result()
            if result.assets:
                for asset in result.assets:
                    logging.info('emailing report')# to %s' % user.email)
                    message = mail.EmailMessage(sender='noreply@bnano.se',
                                    subject='Report %s %s' % (user.firstname, user.lastname))
                    message.body = 'Here is the monthly report'
                    message.to = 'niklasro@gmail.com'
                    message.bcc = 'fridge@koolbusiness.com'
                    message.attachments = ['report.pdf', asset.data]
                    message.send()
                    logging.info('message sent')
```

How can I resolve the status 405 and get through the execution?

Thank you

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I came from GAE/J-land, so I am not familiar with Python, but I had encountered `405` response from my taskqueue worker before. In my case, it is caused due to setting the `TaskOption` method to `POST` while building the `Task`, while my handler only serves `GET` requests.

EDIT: After checking the [TaskQueue.add() docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/taskqueue/functions.html#add), it appears that the default method used if the method is not specified (as in your code example) is POST, while your handler appear to only able to serve GET requests.

My suggestion would be explicitly specify that your task uses GET method instead of POST, or change the handled method of your handler into POST instead of GET.

Comment: Thanks, I found out it was the same for me - it was making an http `POST` instead of a `GET`

Answer (score 1):

Just want to add one possible scenario since a quick search of "**taskqueue 405**" all ends up in this page:

I got 405 errors because didn't specify a "target" parameter. `taskqueue.add()` ends up adding task to the default target, where my handlers are on a separate backend module.

> If target is unspecified, then tasks are invoked on the same version
>   of the application where they were enqueued. So, if you enqueued a
>   task from the default application version without specifying a target
>   on the queue, the task is invoked in the default application version.